# Given a fixed path connected topological space $X$, is "$Y$ is homotopy equivalent with $X$" always strictly weaker than "$Y \approx X$"?

Tags: general-topology

$\simeq$ will denote homotopy equivalence, and $\approx$ will denote homeomorphism.

Given many spaces, it is easy to show this property, for example using the fact that $X \times I \simeq X$, where $I$ denotes the unit interval $[0,1]$.  But it is not as clear (in fact I'm not sure it's true) that homotopy equivalence with a given space is strictly weaker than homeomorphism.  For example $I^{\mathbb{Z}}$ taken as a product is homeomorphic to $I^{\mathbb{Z}} \times I$, so the method I gave doesn't work in general.  Of course, $I^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is also homotopy equivalent to a point, so this is far from a counterexample.

Any kind of proof, proof sketch, or reference would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any set $Y$, $X \times I^Y \simeq X$, by much the same proof that $X \times I \simeq X$. But if $Y$ is sufficiently large - say strictly greater cardinality than $X$, so $I^Y$ and so $X \times I^Y$ also have strictly greater cardinality than $X$, then we cannot have $X \times I^Y \approx X$, since any homeomorphism is in particular a bijection.